# LINQ to entities is ignoring my orderby statement

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, linq-to-entities

I have the following code:

```
var myCats = _context.Cats.Where(c => c.OwnerId == 1).OrderBy(c => c.Age);

var uniqueCatIds = myCats.Select(c => c.CatId).Distinct();
```

For some reason, the `OrderBy` clause is ignored when I examine the output SQL using the profiler. What I want to do is select all the unique cat Ids in the same order as they appear in myCats, and preserve the IQueryable nature of the request.

If I put `.ToList()` after the OrderBy, the ordering appears in the SQL and it works. However with so many cats it is very slow to do this.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with an intermediate projection:

```
var myCats = _context.Cats.Where(c => c.OwnerId == 1).OrderBy(c => c.Age).Select(c => new { c.Age, c.CatId });

var uniqueCatIds = myCats.Select(c => c.CatId).Distinct();
```

The query is still fully executed on the DB.

or by using the `GroupBy`

```
var uniqueCatIds = myCats.GroupBy(c => c.CatId).Select(c => c.Key);
```

(this second query both with your `myCats` and/or my `myCats` variant)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following code will return the required results:

```
from c in _context.Cats
where c.OwnerId == 1
group c by c.CatId into grouped
orderby grouped.Min(c => c.Age)
select grouped.Key
```